# Pgfplots: link different single-points graphs

Tags: pgfplots

I created the following image

[image]

using the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        compat=newest,%
        /pgf/number format/use comma,%
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,},%
        /pgf/number format/min exponent for 1000 sep=4}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={}, xlabel={}, ylabel={}, zlabel={},%
    legend cell align=left]

        \addplot[red, only marks]
            coordinates {(23.0175,1.64554e-15)};
        \addplot[brown, only marks]
            coordinates {(19.544,12.1362)};
        \addplot[orange, only marks]
            coordinates {(17.3908, 15.9429)};
        \addplot[green, only marks]
            coordinates {(16.3344, 18.2596)};
        \addplot[lime, only marks]
            coordinates {(18.0024, 17.6308)};
        \addplot[olive, only marks]
            coordinates {(19.9158, 10.8752)};
        \addplot[blue, only marks]
            coordinates {(19.798, 7.44025)};
        \addplot[cyan, only marks]
            coordinates {(19.4223, 4.57679)};
        \addplot[teal, only marks]
            coordinates {( 18.9801, 4.98689e-16)};

        \legend{$\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = 0$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{2}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to link all data points with a dotted line. Is it possible to achieve this, also if they represent different graphs of only one coordinate?

Comment: Can you complete your code to a full MWE such that we don't need to guess your preamble to duplicate the issue here?

Comment: @percusse Yes, sorry. Done.

Comment: Re cropping of the right axis: I guess that this results from using `standalone` without a `border` and the following conversion to PNG. Try `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}` instead.

Comment: Why not something like `\addplot[smooth,dotted] coordinates { <all your coordinates in the right order> };`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel As you can see, I need points of different color and at each point must correspond a legend with the angle. For the cropping, is a problem I have also in my full document...

Comment: My suggestion is an addition to your other plots, a tenth one. For the cropping: I can't reproduce this. Maybe this should be another question …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pgfplots`'s `scatter` options seem promisingly (section 4.4.10 in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots)).

## Solution with `scatter`

#### Notes (things I dislike)

- It seems to me that a legend entry for every mark is only doable with classes.
- It is very explicit.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        compat=newest,%
        /pgf/number format/use comma,%
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,},%
        /pgf/number format/min exponent for 1000 sep=4}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={},
  xlabel={},
  ylabel={},
  zlabel={},
  legend cell align=left,
  legend image post style={only marks}
  ]
    \addplot[
      smooth,
      dotted,
      scatter,
      every mark/.append style={solid},
      scatter src=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a=red, b=brown, c=orange, d=green, e=lime, f=olive, g=blue, h=cyan, i=teal}
      ] coordinates {
      (23.0175, 1.64554e-15) [a]
      (19.544, 12.1362) [b]
      (17.3908, 15.9429) [c]
      (16.3344, 18.2596) [d]
      (18.0024, 17.6308) [e]
      (19.9158, 10.8752) [f]
      (19.798, 7.44025) [g]
      (19.4223, 4.57679) [h]
      (18.9801, 4.98689e-16) [i]
    };
    \legend{$\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = 0$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{2}$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

## The (easy) solution from [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76539/pgfplots-link-different-single-points-graphs/76549#comment163922_76539)

I do not prefer this solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title={}, xlabel={}, ylabel={}, zlabel={},legend cell align=left]
    \addplot[red,    only marks] coordinates {(23.0175,1.64554e-15)};
    \addplot[brown,  only marks] coordinates {(19.544,12.1362)};
    \addplot[orange, only marks] coordinates {(17.3908, 15.9429)};
    \addplot[green,  only marks] coordinates {(16.3344, 18.2596)};
    \addplot[lime,   only marks] coordinates {(18.0024, 17.6308)};
    \addplot[olive,  only marks] coordinates {(19.9158, 10.8752)};
    \addplot[blue,   only marks] coordinates {(19.798, 7.44025)};
    \addplot[cyan,   only marks] coordinates {(19.4223, 4.57679)};
    \addplot[teal,   only marks] coordinates {(18.9801, 4.98689e-16)};
    \addplot[smooth,dotted] coordinates {
      (23.0175, 1.64554e-15) (19.544, 12.1362)  (17.3908, 15.9429)
      (16.3344, 18.2596)     (18.0024, 17.6308) (19.9158, 10.8752)
      (19.798, 7.44025)      (19.4223, 4.57679) (18.9801, 4.98689e-16)
    };
    \legend{$\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = -\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = 0$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\gamma = +\frac{\pi}{2}$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

The output is the same as the one above.